# Axes line thickness in ggsurvplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

How to change the axes-line thickness with ticks?

Data:

```
library(survminer)
data <- data.frame(time  =c(1,2,3,4),
                    status=rep(c(1,0),4),
                    n=c(1,2,3,4),
                   grp = c(1,1,0,0))
obj  <- Surv(time = data$time, event=data$status) 
fit <- survfit(obj ~ grp, data = data)
```

My plot:

```
ggsurvplot(
  fit,
  data = data,
  xlim = c(0, 60),
  break.x.by = 20,
  xlab = "Day",
  ylab = c("Survival probability"),
  risk.table = "abs_pct",
  font.x = c(12, face = "bold"),
  font.y = c(12, face = "bold"),
  font.tickslab = c(12),
  font.legend = c(12),
  risk.table.title = "RISK",
  risk.table.col = "black",
  size = 1,
  tables.theme = theme_cleantable() + 
    theme(
      plot.title = element_text(size = 40),
      axis.line.y = element_line(size = 1.5) # Not working
    )
)
```

But it does alter the thickness next to the risk.table

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ggsurvplot` returns a `list`-like object with both a `plot` and `table` item. We can modify the `plot` element directly like this:

```
p = ggsurvplot(##... your code from above)

## just for illustration
class(p)
# [1] "ggsurvplot" "ggsurv"     "list"      
names(p)
# [1] "plot"           "table"          "data.survplot"  "data.survtable"

## adjust the plot theme
p[["plot"]] = p[["plot"]] + theme(axis.line.y = element_line(linewidth = 3))
p
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I thought I could implement it in the main code. I gave it also a try with `km$plot$theme$line$linewidth <- 1.5` and 
`km$plot$theme$axis.ticks$linewidth <- 1.5`

Comment: That works too, but you still need to modify the `axis.line.y` theme element, and give it an `element_line` object. `km$plot$theme$axis.line.y = element_line(linewidth = 3)`