# Changing xaxis and yaxis labels in KM plot using svyjskm

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, survey

I  have a survey data so I am doing my KM plots with svyjskm. I need to make x axis and y axis bigger and bold. I tried everything I can think of but it doesn't work like with regular plot or ggplot functions. Any ideas? Thanks

Tried ouputting as a ggplot and adding a theme.
Tried putting inside of the function. # A sample code pasted from the function

Here is a sample code that I "stole" from the function help

```
library(survey)
data(pbc, package="survival")
pbc$randomized <- with(pbc, !is.na(trt) & trt>0)
biasmodel <- glm(randomized~age*edema,data=pbc)
pbc$randprob <- fitted(biasmodel)
dpbc <- svydesign(id=~1, prob=~randprob, strata=~edema, data=subset(pbc,randomized))
s1 <- svykm(Surv(time,status>0)~sex, design=dpbc)

# I want to change the font of x and y axis, make all numbers (0,700..) bigger and bold
# some version of cex.axis = 1.5?

svyjskm(s1,table = TRUE)
```

Comment: Is this course work? Perhaps this question and answer helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77496802/axes-line-thickness-in-ggsurvplot.

Comment: One method that definitely works is using `bquote`, e.g., `svyjskm(svykm(...plotData...), xlab = bquote(bold('Time-to-event')))`. It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput()` or `reprex::reprex()` and any libraries you are using. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).

Comment: Thanks, Kat - that works for the xlab and ylab but it doesn't work for the fonts of axis values, which is what I am trying to change.  There seems to be no option for changing the arguments like xaxis in  this function.  I will try to get a sample data.  Peter, no this is not for a class and svyjskm is different from both plot and ggplot so the same argumemts don't seem to work.